# Xposed: how to hook a method which is in dynamically loaded dex file?

Tags: android, hook, dex

I have two problems with Xposed Framework:

1. If the method I want to hook is in a dynamically loaded dex, which means the dex is loaded by DexClassLoader or PathClassLoader on the run, the Xposed throws ClassNotFound exception. So how to hook a method in such dex file?
2. If the method I want to hook has custom type parameters, like
   `findAndHookMethod("com.XXX.XXX.XXX", lpparam.classLoader, "getXXX", CustomType.class, new XC_MethodHook() {`
   Eclipse gives me an error says "CustomType can't be resolved". So how to fix it? Should I convert the dex into a jar and put it in the buildpath of my project?

The background is: I'm trying to create an Xposed module to hook a method in another app.

Comment: did you try using the classloader provided by DexClassLoader instead of lpparam.classLoader in the findAndHookMethod?

Answer (score 1):

For #2, use reflection to get a Class object for the parameter you want. The Xposed framework provides a convenient helper method for this:

```
    Class classCustomType = XposedHelpers.findClass("com.package.name.CustomType", lpparam.classLoader);
    findAndHookMethod("com.XXX.XXX.XXX", lpparam.classLoader, "getXXX", classCustomType, new XC_MethodHook() {
        //hook the method
    });
```